# Pipelined Sed does not work on found filename inside Bash command substitution when invoked from Find "-exec"

Tags: bash, sed, pipe, command-substitution

It looks like 'find', 'bash' and 'sed' in some cases does not work as one expects.

The following example should first create file 'sample.txt', then find the file and finally process it by '-exec' command. The executed command prints found filename, test specimens, and modified filename. The 'sed' command itself is used to replace 'txt' to 'TXT'.

```
touch sample.txt
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" -exec echo {} $(echo Specimen_before.txt {} Specimen_after.txt |sed -e "s/txt/TXT/g") \;
```

The expected output is:

> ./sample.txt Specimen_before.TXT ./sample.TXT Specimen_after.TXT

Instead it produces:

> ./sample.txt Specimen_before.TXT ./sample.txt Specimen_after.TXT

(the example has been tested also with old-school command substitution through backquotes '`' with the same result)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect `sed -e "s/txt/TXT/g"` to leave alone the second `txt`? `{}` is expanded before `sed` gets to see it.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. I expect the "echo Specimen_before.txt {} Specimen_after.txt" gets printed by the echo, then it gets processed by the sed "|sed -e "s/txt/TXT/g"". I assume the {} expansion is done before the whole '-exec' command is invoked.

Comment: Ok, not I got it. Both  Satō Katsura and Kusalananda answers lead me to understand that the "command substitution is executed before find even starts".

Comment: I actually think @SatōKatsura's comment is slightly wrong. `{}` is expanded by `find`, _after_ `sed` has seen it ("it" being the string `{}`).

Comment: You are right, the sed is invoked before find due to the shell command substitution, which is done before the find is executed by the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command substitution is executed before `find` even starts. The actual command executed (after substitutions, expansions and quote removals etc.) is

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name *.txt -exec echo {} Specimen_before.TXT {} Specimen_after.TXT ;
```

---

If you need to run *anything* fancy (pipes or multiple commands) with `-exec`, then start a separate shell to do it:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' \
    -exec sh -c 'printf "%s " "$1"; printf "%s %s %s\n" "before.txt" "$1" "after.txt" | sed "s/txt/TXT/g"' sh {} ';'
```

Comment: I got it. Your "The command substitution is executed before find even starts." is the answer.